# C strcmp behaving strangely

Tags: c, char, compare, strcmp

Okay im not sure if this is me or something else, but im really confused.

Im trying to find the first occurence of a string inside another string (just like InString() from C++), but from C and doing it with strcmp().

I got two char arrays, string[] and toFind[], and im going through them in two for() loops comparing each char with strcmp().

Here is the Code:

```
int inString(char string[], char toFind[]){

int i_toFind, i_string, check = 0, start = -1;

for(i_toFind = 0; i_toFind < getLength(toFind)-1; i_toFind++){

    for(i_string = 0; i_string < getLength(string)-1; i_string++){

        if(strcmp(&string[i_string], &toFind[i_toFind])==0){

            printf("%i & %i == %i\n", string[i_string], toFind[i_toFind], strcmp(&string[i_string], &toFind[i_toFind]));

            if(start == -1){
                start = i_string;
            }

            check++;
            i_toFind++;

            if(check == getLength(toFind)-1){
                return start;
            }

        }
        else{

            printf("%i & %i == %i\n", string[i_string], toFind[i_toFind], strcmp(&string[i_string], &toFind[i_toFind]));

            check = 0;
            start = -1;

        }

    }

}

return -1;

}
```

Now this works for example for this values:

```
string[] = "hello my friend"
toFind[] = "friend"

result:

104 & 102 == 2
101 & 102 == -1
108 & 102 == 6
108 & 102 == 6
111 & 102 == 9
32 & 102 == -70
109 & 102 == 7
121 & 102 == 19
32 & 102 == -70
102 & 102 == 0
114 & 114 == 0
105 & 105 == 0
101 & 101 == 0
110 & 110 == 0
100 & 100 == 0
```

But for this is does not work:

```
string[] = "friday friend comes"
toFind[] = "friend"

result:

102 & 102 == -1
114 & 102 == 12
105 & 102 == 3
100 & 102 == -2
97 & 102 == -5
121 & 102 == 19
32 & 102 == -70
102 & 102 == 22
114 & 102 == 12
105 & 102 == 3
101 & 102 == -1
110 & 102 == 8
100 & 102 == -2
32 & 102 == -70
99 & 102 == -3
111 & 102 == 9
109 & 102 == 7
101 & 102 == -1
115 & 102 == 13
102 & 114 == -12
114 & 114 == -1
105 & 114 == -9
...
```

The interesting part is this:

```
102 & 102 == -1
114 & 114 == -1
```

Should this not be 0 when equal? Or what am i missing here?
The function i have written seems only to fail if the word im searching is NOT the last one in string[].

Hope someone can actually find my mistake.. Thanks!

UPDATE:

The code where i run InString() is only one line:

```
printf("Beginn: %i\n", inString(string, substring));
```

UPDATE 2:

Here is a simple example of the problem:

```
int inString(char string[], char toFind[]){

    const char *pointer_toStart = strstr(string, toFind);

    return pointer_toStart ? pointer_toStart - string : -1;

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char string[300], substring[300];

    printf("String: ");

    fgets(&test, 20, stdin); // To capture the one '\n' inside the buffer (just ignore this line)
    fgets(string, 300, stdin);

    printf("toFind: ");

    fgets(substring, 300, stdin);

    printf("Beginn: %i\n", inString(string, substring));

}
```

Comment: You can't use `strcmp` to compare individual characters.

Comment: Since you're using c string functions why not replace `getLength` with `strlen`?

Comment: strstr() may be the one to use.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `strstr()`?  If you're trying to implement `strstr()`, it is not clear that `strcmp()` is a useful function; you might be able to use `strncmp()`, but even that's more likely to be problematic than doing the job on characters rather than strings.

Comment: getLength() is using strlen, so its basically the same. Im not using strstr() because thats giving me a pointer right? How would i get the starting position of the searched string from that?

Comment: The pointer returned by `strstr()` is a pointer to the start of the first occurrence of the 'needle' string in the 'haystack' string — or a null pointer if the needle isn't found in the haystack.  If you need the offset to the start of the string, then `retval - start` gives you the number you need.

Comment: Ye i know that thats a pointer to the searched string, but how exactly would i convert a char *pointer to a int telling me the starting index?

Comment: Is not a wrong behavior, just wrong used

Comment: sry, temp brain lapse ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `strcmp` to compare portions of C strings, you can use `memcmp` for that.  But there is a simpler approach to your question using `strstr`.

Here is a simple implementation of inString as per your implicit specification.

```
#include <string.h>

int inString(const char *string, const char *toFind) {
    const char *p = strstr(string, toFind);
    return p ? p - string : -1;
}
```

The function returns the starting index of the substring if found and `-1` if not found.

With this implementation, the following test correctly prints `25`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "Friede freude Eierkuchen freuen sich freundlich";
    char toFind[] = "freuen";

    printf("inString(\"%s\", \"%s\") -> %d\n", string, toFind, inString(string, toFind));
    return 0;
}
```

In your test code, you use `fgets` to read the strings from standard input. Both strings will likely contain a final `'\n'` and therefore you will not find a match for `"freuen\n"` unless it is at the end of `string` that also has a final `'\n'`.  Correct this by removing the `'\n'`.  Here is a simple way to strip it that also works if it is not there:

```
string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = '\0';
toFind[strcspn(toFind, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Comment: wow thanks for the answer! Could you explain me what the last line (where the value is returned) does? (Never seen this syntax tho..)

Comment: The ternary operator is like an if/then/else expression.  last line could be written this way: `if (p != NULL) return p - string; else return -1;`.  The compiler will probably generate the exact same code for both versions.

Comment: Thank you very much! sadly, it also does not seem to work for all strings: string[] = "friede freude eierkuchen freuen sich freundlich" | toFind[] = "freuen" | result = -1

Comment: Ternary operator is the Ugliest C Operator :))

Comment: Well that could be true but why is strstr() also failing exact the same way as my selfimplementation did?

Comment: Seems like both methods (my one and strstr()) can only fiend the searched string when it is at the end of the whole string, else they always return -1. Why is that so?

Comment: Not at all. `strstr` does exactly what you want.  The problem is elsewhere.  Can you edit your question and post the code where you call `inString()` ?  My version returns `25`.

Comment: I updated it, or do you need more code? (eg how i input the two arrays?)

Comment: Can you post the complete code of a simple example that shows failure.  I suspect the definition of `string` and/or `toFind` is not exactly what you imply in your comments.

Comment: I updated the code, thats how my programm looks like (well, broken down to the problem).

Comment: I was right in suspecting another problem. I updated my answer.

Comment: Always theese null terminators and new lines.. dump me. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all much thanks to chqrlie for helping me that much and pointing me to the right direction.

I tryed what you mentioned, removing the '\n' from string[] and toFind[], but i still ended in the same issue.

What solved it for me was using my method posted at the beginning, but instead of strcmp() using memcmp(). That did it. So here is my inString() how it looks like now:

```
int inString(char string[], char toFind[]){

     int i_toFind, i_string, check = 0, start = -1;

     for(i_toFind = 0; i_toFind < getLength(toFind)-1; i_toFind++){

       for(i_string = 0; i_string < getLength(string); i_string++){

         if(memcmp(&string[i_string], &toFind[i_toFind], 1)==0){

           if(start == -1){

             start = i_string;

           }

           check++;
           i_toFind++;

           if(check == getLength(toFind)-1){
             return start;
           }

         }
         else{

         i_toFind = i_toFind - check;

         check = 0;
         start = -1;

         }

       }

     }

     return -1;

}
```

does give me also 25 on the example mentioned above.

Comment: Your function is still way too complicated. Instead of using `memcmp` to compare 1 byte at a time, for which a simple `==` operator would suffice, use it to compare `strlen(toFind)` bytes at successive positions in `string`, from `0` to `strlen(string)-strlen(toFind)` inclusive.  First compute the string lengths amd use a single `for` loop for the tests, return the first matching offset, and `-1` if all comparisons fail.